# How to convert an IPv4 address into a integer and back in C?

Tags: c

for example in Python:

```
number = struct.unpack('!L', socket.inet_aton(ip))[0]
ip = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L',number))
```

Comment: did the google stoped working? why there are so many such questions here?

Comment: @Ulterior: Actually, SO is so popular that even Google looks for answers here.

Comment: @mouviciel, google is so omnivorous that he condescends even to looking for answers on SO :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inet_addr`, `inet_aton`, `inet_ntoa`, there are quite a few functions, try looking up the documentation.